# Adding new block in admin order section

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, sales-order

I have added a new block in admin sales order page. The strange thing is it doesn't appear when i open order create page. But when i reload it appears. Can anyone tell what i am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.

In sales admin order, i had added a block in sales_order_create_index.xml file. This was showing the block when i reload the page. There was one more file name sales_order_create_load_block_data.xml, where i didn't inserted the new block. Entering my block in this file solved the problem.